# Crash in MetalContext with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios

We have a crash in MetalContext with over 3000 crashes in a single day on iOS 10 devices only. We are unable to track down the root of the error and google reveals nobody else have the same issue. Is there anyone who has any clues to where we can begin to look?

```
CRASH_INFO_ENTRY_0
Assertion failed: (_mcimpl->device == [_mcimpl->queue device]), function MetalContext, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/QuartzCore/QuartzCore-449.40.9/LayerKit/ogl/ogl-metal.mm, line 1005.

tid_403
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18d19e8e8 __ulock_wait + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18d06c0d8 _dispatch_ulock_wait + 48
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18d06c200 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 36
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x18d069df8 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 236
4  QuartzCore                     0x1913e7090 CABackingStoreGetFrontTexture(CABackingStore*) + 92
5  QuartzCore                     0x1913e7118 CABackingStorePrepareFrontTexture + 64
6  QuartzCore                     0x1914db0a4 CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*) + 320
7  QuartzCore                     0x1914577f8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 264
8  QuartzCore                     0x19147ec58 CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
9  QuartzCore                     0x19147f678 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 120
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18e17b7dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18e17940c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18e17989c __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18e0a8048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
14 GraphicsServices               0x18fb2e198 GSEventRunModal + 180
15 UIKit                          0x1940942fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
16 UIKit                          0x19408f034 UIApplicationMain + 208
17 NDC2010                        0x100a321d4 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr (<unknown>:1)
18 NDC2010                        0x1009ae138 Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string (UIApplication.cs:63)
19 NDC2010                        0x100526288 NDC2010_NDC2010_NDC2010Application_Main_string__ + 28620
20 NDC2010                        0x100921ba4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 4204776
21 Mono                           0x1019aa4e8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1772
22 Mono                           0x101a1ad64 do_runtime_invoke + 112
23 Mono                           0x101a1d348 mono_runtime_exec_main + 832
24 Mono                           0x101a1cf64 mono_runtime_run_main + 764
25 Mono                           0x10198eb04 mono_jit_exec + 236
26 NDC2010                        0x10051ed3c xamarin_main (monotouch-main.m:487)
27 NDC2010                        0x101291970 main (main.arm64.m:133)
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x18d08c5b8 (Missing)
```

Answer (score 1):

My app kept crashing with the same log, what fixed for me was a quick reset of device, i traced it to webView usage. I cant reset device every time so further testing revealed that i was using xcode 7.3 to build for ios10 that was the problem, after updating to xcode 8 and rebuilding the app i no longer get this crash. Hope this helps